# HP Pavillion dm3 (Windows 7) BSOD,

Tags: windows-7, bsod

HI I have a HP Pavilion dm3.  It came up with a BSOD and then didn't give me an option to start up in safe mode.

I dont have any cd drive, nor did it come with a Windows cd anyway.  I presume that it has a partition in my laptop for that kinda stuff. I was hoping to boot it using a usb but I don't know how to do it or where to download the stuff from.  I have access to network computers, so am able to download from the internet but it's not a Windows7 computer.

I am able to download from the computers that I have access to, but unable to run any executable files on them.

Can someone please help?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a USB thumb drive. I think 8 GB is enough.

Please go  and download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) which is very easy to use and lightweight. You can create a bootable device with the ISO image you have. But I think you have to do this on other computers.

Restart your computer. Change your [BIOS boot order](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=18703&docname=c00364979). You have to choose USB Device and save the settings. Then, there you go. Hope it helps. (Welcome to SuperUser)

Comment: Thanks.  But where do i get the iso image from - does it have to be from a windows7 computer or can any network computer do?  If any network computer is fine, how do I get it anyway?

Comment: You can get some ISO here ( http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/ ) but you already must have a license key or have to purchase.

Comment: I suspect that is the product key at the bottom of my laptop with pretty scruffed numbers and letters.  Will try to see if I can still obtain the numbers.  How do I know which Windows 7 I am on?  Thanks

Comment: It's likely to be Windows 7 Home Premium x86 (32-bit) and Yes, you can try the product key you have. Else, if it's still under warranty, you should try calling HP.

Comment: thanks.  I have now copy the ISO file plus the rufus.exe onto a usb drive.  Can I just put the usb into my laptop and try to change the bios settings?

Comment: woops, that didn't work.  Realised you meant to run the rufus.exe and open up the iso file, yeah?   But unable to do that on a network computer.  What next?